# Which is the fastest hive UDF btw LIKE , get_json_object and json_stupple

Tags: sql, json, string, hiveql, getjson

I am working on an hive query that needs to count an enormous amount of data reported in a table like this one:

```
table[ |column_name      | 
       |    (...)        |
       |{"data":"number"}| 
           (...)         ]
```

The performance of my query is important cause of the number of data I have to treat.

By searching on the web I found three methods to do this. Does some people know which is the fastest? or can propose another method which is faster than those three?

1. ```
   SELECT count(*) FROM table WHERE column LIKE TRIM('{"data":"number"}')
   ```
2. ```
   SELECT count(*) FROM table WHERE get_json_object(column,'$.data)=="number"
   ```
3. ```
   SELECT count(*) FROM (
      SELECT json_tuple(column,'number') FROM table) AS new_column
      WHERE new_column.col1 = number
   ```

Comment: You are right with keeping the three code parst separate in a numbered list (via undoing the well-meaning edit). Allow me (or the quick-typing Adriaan) to help you do that still with code formatting, which I consider helpful. You can find helpful info like that on the [tour], at [ask] and from https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Hm, indeed the markdown renderer is a bit off my expectation with the "1)".... I do not find an error in @Adriaan s  edit/markdown....